# Why can't I root my Zenfone 2 android device?

Tags: rooting, root-access, custom-roms, installation

I have managed to install TWRP, unblocked the bootloader, but I simply can't root my device.

I have tried this: http://www.asus-zenfone.com/2016/05/how-to-root-asus-zenfone-2-laser-ze50kl-marshmallow.html

I have also tried this one:
http://technoplanners.blogspot.in/2016/02/root-asus-zenfone-2-laser.html

It doesn't work either.

Do I even need root access for a custom ROM installation?

I am trying to install Ressurecition Remix. I was wondering if that grants root access during the installation?

Comment: I don't know why can't you? What problem do you encounter? Is it simply not working where it should or does it give an error?

Comment: It looks all fine (I mean it gives no error message), but then when I check it with the app..it says the device is not rooted.

I have just tried again from this website:http://technoplanners.blogspot.com/2016/02/root-asus-zenfone-2-laser.html

and it gives this error message in adb:

"downloading 'boot.img'...
OKAY [  0.669s]
booting...
FAILED (remote: dtb not found)
finished. total time: 0.690s
"

Comment: Add that to your question. Your question, as is, very non-detailed and is very hard to answer. Detail it to your best effort to boost your chance of someone posting a good answer that'll solve your problem.

Comment: Ok. I'll do my best, but I just simply want to root my asus device and none of the 2 tutorials cited can do so. It's weird. There seems to be no definite solution to rooting asus zenfone 2 laser ZE500KL devices. A bit weird.

I dont get any error messages, nothing....but then when I check it, it is not rooted.

Comment: What is the output of adb shell su ? does it change from $ to # ?